# Laravel 4 Login. How can I add custom data in Auth::user()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, authentication

Firstly, I use this code for login:

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
```

Login is good, but Auth::user() does not keep the data I want. I try this code to add some data:

```
Auth::user()->setAttribute('info', "aa");
```

But it's not working. The error text is:

```
 {"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to a member function setAttribute() on null","file": ....
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I login in Laravel correctly or what is the right way add items into Auth::user()?

Comment: What does `dd(Auth::user());` print out?

Comment: Looks like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking about possibly wrong solution explain in detail what are you really trying to accomplish and why.

Comment: @Bogdan setAttribute method is not defined. My error is "Call to a member function setAttribute() on null". It didn't add anything.